# How does the Real Canonical Form help solve the matrix exponential?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the system $\vec{x'}=$$ \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     -13 & -10 \\
     20 & 15
  \end{array} \right]
$ $\vec{x}$

I found that the canonical form for the matrix is 
$$ \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     1 & 2 \\
     -2 & 1
  \end{array} \right]
$$ 
since the eigenvalues were $1\pm 2i$. I am trying to finish the initial problem using this canonical form I found. I am confused what its purpose is to be completely honest..

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure of what you want to denote, but if it is $\;\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\-2&1\end{bmatrix}$, this is *not* a Jordan canonical form.

Comment: I thought that the 2x2 case of the jordan canonical form for a matrix A with complex eigenvalues a+-bi is [a, b; -b, a]

Comment: Oh maybe I mean real canonical form... http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~jmckinno/Math225/Week11/Lecture3s.pdf

Comment: As far as I know, Jordan canonical form exists only in case of characteristic polynomials that split into linear factors. Maybe there exists a convention in the case of quadratic irreducible factors, but basically it's only the first case. Anyway, it's simpler to work with complex valued functions.

Comment: Ya thats correct. I can add more details if need be.

Comment: Let me rewrite it... just a few minutes please.. thanks

Comment: Ok I rewrote the question...

Comment: @Moo thank you so much. I can't thank you enough. This is starting to click for me I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are given

$$x'= \begin{bmatrix}
     -13 & -10 \\
     20 & 15
  \end{bmatrix}
x$$

**Method 1 (M1):** Using Eigenvalues / Eigenvectors

We find the eigenvalues from the characteristic polynomial given by $|A - \lambda I| = 0$ as

$$\lambda_{1,2} = 1~ \pm~ 2 i$$

The corresponding eigenvectors are
$$v_{1, 2} = (-7 ~ \pm ~i,10)$$

We can now write $A = P_{M1} D P_{M1}^{-1}$ where $P_{M1}$ are the column eigenvectors and $D$  the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues. Because we have unique eigenvalues, $D$ is a diagonal matrix (no Jordan block).

This easily allows us to find the matrix exponential as

$$e^{A t} = P_{M1} e^{D t} P_{M1}^{-1} = e^t \begin{bmatrix}
  \cos (2 t)-7  \sin (2 t) & -5  \sin (2 t) \\
 10  \sin (2 t) & \cos (2 t)+7  \sin (2 t) \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

**Method 2 (M2):** Real Canonical Form

**(Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff Theorem):** Suppose we attempt to define a matrix
$C$ by $e^C = e^A~e^B$. If the commutator $[A, B] = AB − BA = 0$, then $C = A + B$.

If a matrix can be written as a sum of two commuting matrices whose exponentials
can be computed, then exponentiation is easy because we can exploit $[aI, b \sigma] = 0$ using the previous theorem. For example,

$$B = \begin{bmatrix}
     a & b \\
     -b & a
  \end{bmatrix} = a I + b \sigma \implies e^{B t} = e^{a ~I ~t} e^{b~ \sigma~ t} = e^{at}\begin{bmatrix}
     \cos(bt) & \sin(b t) \\
     -\sin(bt) & \cos(b t)
  \end{bmatrix}$$

We already found the eigenvalues and eigenvectors above. Using $\lambda_1 = 1 + 2 i$ and $v_1 = (-7 + ~i,10)$, we set $v = u + i w$ as

$$u = \begin{bmatrix}
     -7 \\
     10
  \end{bmatrix}, w = \begin{bmatrix}
     1 \\
     0
  \end{bmatrix} \implies P_{M2} = \begin{bmatrix}
     -7 & 1 \\
    10 & 0
  \end{bmatrix} \implies P_{M2}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
 0 & \dfrac{1}{10} \\
 1 & \dfrac{7}{10} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

We can now write the Real Canonical Form as

$$B = P_{M2}^{-1} A P_{M2} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 2 \\
 -2 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \implies e^{B t} = e^t\begin{bmatrix}
 \cos(2t) & \sin(2t) \\
 -\sin(2t) & \cos(2t) 
\end{bmatrix}$$

We now compute

$$e^{At} = P_{M2} e^{B t} P_{M2}^{-1} = 
e^t
\begin{bmatrix}
  \cos (2 t)-7 \sin (2 t) & -5  \sin (2 t) \\
 10  \sin (2 t) & \cos (2 t)+7 \sin (2 t) \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Compare both results.